# Is my raster catalog managed or unmanaged?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, raster-catalog

According to the following post I can look in the field properties to find out if my raster catalog is managed or unmanaged.

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/02/15/is-my-raster-catalog-managed-or-unmanaged/

However, when I look, I do not have the property "Managed by GBD". I have both ArcGIS 10.0 and 10.3.1. How else can I find out which Raster Catalog I have?

Here you can see what is shown when I show the properties of the raster field.

[image: RasterCatalog Properties]

Comment: I tested with arcgis 10.2.2 and it's there. once in the fields property page, make sure to click on the Raster (type: raster)  field. and you will see it in the field properties section (at the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was initially promising that you would be able to use the [Describe Function](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/describe.htm) ArcPy function to pull the [Field Properties](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/field.htm). However, ESRI has not made any Properties in the Syntax to be able to get the Managed by GDB property (seen in the Field Properties image below)  [image: Raster]

This is a bit of a stop-gap solution but you can add the Raster Catalog to ArcMap>Open Attribute Table>View the Field Properties. In there you may be able to get the information to populate. [image: Field]

The only issue here is that if the Field does not exist in the first place it will probably not populate in the Field Properties of the Attribute Table.

You could always try to upgrade the Geodatabase to see if that fixes it. 
[image]